# How To Use Unity With C++?

Tags: unity, c++

In the C++ `Visual Studio` installer, there is an option `Game Development With Unity`. However, after selecting that, I didn't find any changes to regular `Visual Studio`. So I looked it up, and found no results regarding C++. How can I use `Unity` with `Visual Studio` for C++?

Answer (score 3):

The Visual Studio Tools for Unity are primarily for writing C# scripts. They don't expose a C++ scripting API.

The reason they show up when you're working with C++ in Visual Studio is they're related to VS, not C++ specifically. VS will let you develop in several different languages in a single installation, so they don't rule out the possibility that you might want to use C++ for some projects and Unity C# for others.

You *can* use C++ to build a [native plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html) to call from Unity scripts, though you usually need to do this only to access specialized platform-specific features that the engine hasn't exposed to the C# API in a platform-agnostic fashion.